# How can I remove duplicate icons for "launched" java programs in the launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher, java

When launching java programs (like IntelliJ IDEA and Crashplan) in Natty's Unity launcher, duplicate icons are shown (see image).  For IntelliJ I created the .desktop file, for Crashplan the .desktop file is supplied with the application.  Is there something that can be changed in the .desktop files (or somewhere else) that can prevent this from occurring?  I couldn't find a bug report for unity itself but programs like Gnome-Do/Docky have [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/docky/+bug/484610) [reports](https://bugs.launchpad.net/do/+bug/317076) and had to make internal changes to their applications to prevent this.

[image: Duplicate Icons] In this image the 1st icon is the one created from the .desktop file and the second icon is after launching it.  Second icon disappears when closing the application.

Custom IntelliJ .desktop file

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon[en_US]=/opt/idea/bin/idea128.png
Name[en_US]=IntelliJ IDEA
Exec=/opt/idea/bin/idea.sh
Name=IntelliJ IDEA
Icon=/opt/idea/bin/idea128.png
StartupNotify=true
```

Crashplan provide .desktop file

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=CrashPlan
Categories=;
Comment=CrashPlan Desktop UI
Comment[en_CA]=CrashPlan Desktop UI
Exec=/usr/local/crashplan/bin/CrashPlanDesktop
Icon=/usr/local/crashplan/skin/icon_app_64x64.png
Hidden=false
Terminal=false
Type=Application
GenericName[en_CA]=
```

Comment: I experience a similar issue when launching Minecraft in Unity

Comment: Thanks God the problem gets affecting mainstream users (it used to be a problem for AWN and other dock enthusiasts only) finally. I hope Java (and not only Java) applications developers will consider fixing this now. By the way, Eclipse seems to have no such a problem, while I've never managed to fix this for MySQL Workbench and OpenOffice.org (tried when I was using AWN, before LibreOffice has emerged) .

Comment: The problem is about applications to use stupid not-identifying WM_CLASS names as far as I can remember.

Comment: If there there was no such a problem, I would for sure use Unity or AWN. But so far as not every application supports them perfectly, I prefer a traditional taskbar (because I hate half-solutions).

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Add a **StartupWMClass** string into your .desktop file. Use `xprop` command to get this class. For example :

```
$ xprop|grep WM_CLASS
 WM_CLASS(STRING) = "sun-awt-X11-XFramePeer", "java-lang-Thread"

$ cat /usr/share/applications/PHPStorm.desktop | grep StartupWM
StartupWMClass=sun-awt-X11-XFramePeer
```

More deatils in [this](https://answers.launchpad.net/awn/+question/116656) thread (this about AWN, but works for Unity too)

Comment: This works great for Crashplan `StartupWMClass=CrashPlan` but IntelliJ needed a little more convincing.  I had to use info from this (http://blog.jteam.nl/2011/01/09/make-intellij-idea-behave-properly-in-linux-docks/) to get it working properly.

Comment: As a small aside to update IntelliJ I modified the idea.vmoptions not the idea.sh script directly.  Add `-javaagent:agent.jar=IntelliJ_IDEA` to the file.

Comment: With IntelliJ 11 the agent.jar is no longer necessary.  StartupWMClass=jetbrains-idea

Comment: And `jetbrains-idea-ce` for the Community Edition. PS, thanks a bunch Tim, 451F.

Comment: The problem `sun-awt-X11-XFramePeer` is not unique. For example NetBeans and VisualVM use `"sun-awt-X11-XFramePeer", "java-lang-Thread"` too. Fortunately IntelliJ Idea has switched to `"sun-awt-X11-XFramePeer", "jetbrains-idea"` but there is still intersection with "sun-awt-X11-XFramePeer". Is there a way to specify both parts of `WM_CLASS(STRING)` with `StartupWMClass`?

Comment: @Ivan: you don't have to use both, you can use *either* one. So if `jetbrains-idea` is the unique one, the one you want, use it *instead* of `sun-awt-X11-XFramePeer`

Comment: sun-awt-X11-XFramePeer is the default WM_CLASS for many (every?) Java applications, so it's never a good idea to use it; it's better to use the other Class you see using xprop.

Comment: This works fine for RubyMine on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: You saved my life! Those duplicated icons were driving me crazy!

Answer (score 9):

For Intellij Idea 11 under Ubuntu 11.10 is necessary to add at the idea's .desktop file following line:

```
StartupWMClass=jetbrains-idea
```

Answer (score 4):

I was able to fix this for SQLDeveloper, which is a java program:

Using xprop (and then clicking on the SQLDeveloper window), I found the following line of output:

```
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "sun-awt-X11-XFramePeer", "oracle-ide-boot-Launcher"
```

Based on the comments found above and in https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/757991, I added the following line to my local sqldeveloper.desktop file:

```
StartupWMClass=oracle-ide-boot-Launcher
```

Comment: In SQLDeveloper version 4 WM_CLASS changed to "sun-awt-X11-XFramePeer", "oracle-ide-osgi-boot-OracleIdeLauncher", so the .desktop parameter should changed to : StartupWMClass=oracle-ide-osgi-boot-OracleIdeLauncher

Answer (score 2):

I've documented the fix for Eclipse 4.x and 3.x [here](http://glx-dock.org/bg_topic.php?t=7029).

This solution is for glx-dock aka Cairo-dock but works for all task bars relying on `WM_CLASS`.

In the case of eclipse, the launch is a two step process as well.

[image]

Basically, what you need to do is to identify Eclipse branding plugin.xml applicable to your Eclipse version and modify the `application name` property.  When the workbench main windows is created, Jface will call the SWT `Display.setName` and this will set you WM_CLASS.  If this is the declared WM_CLASS for your launcher, then running instances will find their dock launcher.

Don't forget to do `eclipse -clean` on the first time.

Tabbing through is also much improved.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ IDEA is started by a script ($IDEA_HOME/bin/idea.sh). When its launcher is clicked, the script is executed, which starts a java executable and immediately exits. Unity notices that the application you started (the script) has already exited - that's why there is no indicator on the first IDEA icon. However, there is an other (from the executable started by the launcher) application running at the moment - and that's why the second IDEA icon is shown.

I hope the fix for this behavior will be implemented soon - but it is not a very straightforward one. It would have to involve a hand-maintained list associations between windows and launchers they should be associated with.

Answer (score 0):

For CrashPlan, you can try moving your app file CrashPlan.desktop to /usr/share/applications. Only apps that live there can be locked into the launcher.

```
sudo mv ~/Desktop/CrashPlan.desktop /usr/share/applications/.
```

Then try using the dash to run CrashPlan.

You might be able to do something similar with IntelliJ IDEA, but since it's running a script, I'm not sure if it will work correctly.

Comment: I have both .desktop files in ~/.local/share/applications and don't have any issues locking them to the launcher.  I am assuming that you mean available to be launched from Launcher but not yet launched when you say locked...

Comment: Hm. I'm not able to place them in the launcher. I made mine with alacarte (Menu Editor). Maybe it's because I have ~/.local linked to somewhere else... Do your apps show the running triangle (left side) and the active triangle (right side)?

Comment: For the "launched" version of the icon, yes.  You can see the running triangle in the first shot.  I did some more research and think I have a working workaround for the duplicate icons.  Will post an answer here.

Comment: @451F beat me to the answer, I added a bit to his answer in my comments on how to get IntelliJ to work better.

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers worked for me, but in the end I actually found an even simpler solution.

Open up Intellij-Idea, and on the top bar find the **tools** dropdown menu. Then, select the **Create Desktop Entry** button. It'll create a properly working .desktop entry in your `.local/share/applications` folder, which should get recognized by whatever desktop environment you're using. It doesn't make a duplicate icon, and you can even change the icon if you want.

Unfortunately, using the `nosplash` argument brings back the duplicate icon problem, so I'm not sure how to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

After installing IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.5 under Ubuntu 17.04 (with Numix icons) I had to change the line `StartupWMClass=jetbrains-idea` to `StartupWMClass=jetbrains-idea-ce` in the program's .desktop file so the duplicate icon would disappear.

I guess "ce" stands for Community Edition which I have, so I don't know why the value of this property in the .desktop file was originally not having the "ce" suffix.