# How do I get high resolution icons in Unity for my application without a .desktop file?

Tags: application-development, icons, gtk

I am trying to fix a problem I found with a [Java application](https://www.willuhn.de/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1310). It has a too low res icon. After reading the source of it I modified it to have a bigger icon. SWT uses the [`gtk_window_set_icon()`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-set-icon) function of GTK to set the icon.

However, the high resolution icon is not used.

There is a work around of using a `.desktop` file to have a nice icon described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90845/pygtk-application-icon-blurred-in-unity). And others describe the problem [on the Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2053292).

So how can I have a nice icon without having to place a `.desktop` file in the filesystem? Where should I report the bug for this? In which package is the code downscaling the icon that I intend to pass to the window manager?

I appreciate some help on this.

This can be reproduced with the following code:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display display = new Display();

    final int SIZE = 256;
    Image large = new Image(display, SIZE, SIZE);
    GC gc = new GC(large);
    gc.setBackground(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_RED));
    gc.fillArc(0, 0, SIZE, SIZE, 45, 270);
    gc.dispose();

    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setImages(new Image[] {  large });

    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
      if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        display.sleep();
    }

    large.dispose();
    display.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: It's probably GTK down-sizing it to something that makes sense in a window's title bar.  Why don't you want to use the .desktop file?

Comment: As it is a Java project most the time it is not even installed. So I cannot copy the `.desktop` file to the appropriate places in the system. Moreover, I am actually using [gtk_window_set_icon_list ()](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-set-icon-list) which passes many icons to GTK, so the right (bigger) one should be chosen for ALT-TAB.

Comment: @FelixMöller I feel that's more of an answer! Please post answers as answers.

Comment: I see no solution at all. I just tried to explain why I do not want to use a `.desktop` file.