# Chrome won't start

Tags: google-chrome

I upgraded Ubuntu to 12.04.

I can't launch Chrome from the taskbar, even though it's the most recent version. In the taskbar, the icon is grayed out with a question mark.

What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue like this posted [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72451/why-do-some-open-applications-appear-as-question-marks-in-the-unity-launcher)

To sum up the issue, it could be one of three things:

1.A bug in [BAMF](https://launchpad.net/bamf) (the application matching framework mentioned above).

2.A faulty [application description](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/) (aka '.desktop' file).

3.The lack of any application description at all. Executables that launch windows do not inherently have this metadata.

This issue is directly related to Unity's framework.

I can't sum it up very well, but if you go to the [link above](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72451/why-do-some-open-applications-appear-as-question-marks-in-the-unity-launcher) it has a thorough explanation of the issue.

Comment: I see. So is there a way to open it without the taskbar? I tried typing in google-chrome in Terminal and it opened, but would doing that cause any problems with permissions?

Comment: No it shouldn't cause any problems at all. Thats probably the best idea is to run it through terminal if you can't fix the icon.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'd upvote your suggestion, but it says I don't have enough points yet.