# Missing icons in the launcher after upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, launcher

After upgrading a particular system from 13.10 to 14.04 there are a few items in the launcher portrayed with a question mark:

[image]

This is not the [old problem of windows mismatching applications](https://askubuntu.com/q/329673/177437). The icon is always rendered this way, no shadow icon is created when the application is running and it gets the visual semantics and behaviour as any other functioning launcher item.

It is neither [a missing icon](https://askubuntu.com/q/329673/177437) or a wrong icon path. Following some shell output regarding one of the applications concerned:

```
$ cat /usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Eclipse
Icon=/usr/local/eclipse.kepler/eclipse.png
Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= /usr/local/eclipse.kepler/eclipse
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;IDE;Java;

$ ls -la /usr/local/eclipse.kepler/eclipse.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 lads lads 53556 Jun 11 19:00 /usr/local/eclipse.kepler/eclipse.png
```

What could then be the cause?

Comment: Eliah, this is a different issue. These icons were permanently portrayed as question marks, even if the application was not running. And as you can see the solution is also different.

Answer (score 1):

This was relatively easy to solve:

1. Right click on the item and click *Remove from Launcher*.
2. With the file browser open the `/usr/share/applications` folder and search for the file corresponding to the application (e.g. Eclipse - in the file system it is named `eclipse.desktop`).
3. Drag this file to the Launcher.

Comment: This fix only works temporarily, after some time the question will be back.

Comment: Is temporary solution acceptable?