# Missing icon after executing shell script to install program

Tags: software-installation, icons, kde, plasma

I tried installing CLion on my KDE Neon and followed the instructions on the site, by extracting the tar archive and executing the shell script in the bin folder. The program launches fine and everything works, but when I go to the application dash and look it up, I see it has no icon. This is how it looks

[image: here]

It is not a major problem but it kinda still bothers me somehow. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I finally solved this problem. 
[Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/329673/how-can-i-fix-program-icons-that-appear-as-a-question-mark-in-the-launcher) is the link to the answer that helped me. I used an online svg to png file converter and the icons work perfectly now :)