# Folder icon is not shown up

Tags: icons, directory

Folders are shown in text icon instead of it's original icon image.How to resolve this?

[image: I have attached the image over here.]

Answer (score 2):

Try this
Login screen combo Ctrl + Alt + F1 enter username and password then run the following commands:

sudo apt-get install dconf-tools

DISPLAY=:0 dconf reset -f /org/compiz/

unity --reset-icons

setsid unity

and finally reboot

Comment: But it didn't work @akgnit

Comment: check out this.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/329673/how-can-i-fix-program-icons-that-appear-as-a-question-mark-in-the-launcher