# How to remove "?" icons from Unity programs list

Tags: 12.04, unity

After running a console program called apitrace I ended up with a bunch of "?" icons in the list of applications in Unity (see screenshot).  It is possible to remove them without restarting my session.  Note that the application that was running that the icons were created for has already terminated.  I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Related: [Why do some open applications appear as “question marks” in the Unity launcher?](http://askubuntu.com/q/72451/52726)

Comment: Have you tried right clicking on them and clicking "quit"? Do they have that option?

Comment: @Alaa This is not a duplicate. He wants to *close* the app that created the icons, not change the icon.

Comment: @seth: I tried right clicking on the icon but there was no option to quit.  The app that created the icons has already exited, I just wanted to remove the ? from the list in the Unit launcher.  The app was launched from the command line so I don't need it to ever be in the launcher list.

Answer (score 0):

The icon launchers are found at `/usr/share/applications` and has the extension `.desktop`, so all you need to do is remove them from there. For safety try to move them to other place instead of remove them.