# How do I install CrashPlan with a Unity Launcher icon?

Tags: unity, launcher, crashplan

I just installed CrashPlan for Linux. After installing, I deleted the installer folder and files, and the icon sitting on my desktop (after dragging it to the launcher). I rebooted, now the launcher icon is gone and I can't find any way to start the CrashPlan Desktop application.

How do I get the launcher back so I can start the program?

Comment: Based on the answers above, I've made a video tutorial at the following URL in case you need further assistance. [Video Tutorial - Installing CrashPlan on Ubuntu](http://echotutorials.com/141/how-to-install-crashplan-with-ubuntu-12-04-unity/tutorial/screencast/guide.php)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Download CrashPlan [for Linux](http://www.crashplan.com/consumer/download.html?os=Linux), saving the .tgz archive on your Desktop.

Double-click on the file to open it with Archive Manager, then extract it to the Desktop.
You should have a folder now named '**CrashPlan-install**' on your Desktop.

Open the Terminal and navigate to the folder containing the installer. Run the install script, using the default choices:

```
cd ~/Desktop/CrashPlan-install
sudo ./install.sh
```

After it finishes, you need to do three things.

1. Edit the .desktop file (to make it compatible with the Unity Launcher).
2. Copy it to  .local/share/applications.
3. Drag it from .local/share/applications onto the launcher.

Edit the .desktop file first:

```
gedit ~/Desktop/CrashPlan-install/scripts/CrashPlan.desktop
```

Add the line '**StartupWMClass=CrashPlan**' at the end, so it looks like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=CrashPlan
Categories=;
Comment=CrashPlan Desktop
Comment[en_CA]=CrashPlan Desktop
Exec=/usr/local/bin/CrashPlanDesktop
Icon=/usr/local/crashplan/skin/icon_app_128x128.png
Hidden=false
Terminal=false
Type=Application
GenericName[en_CA]=
StartupWMClass=CrashPlan
```

Save, and exit the text editor. Now copy the file:

```
cp ~/Desktop/CrashPlan-install/scripts/CrashPlan.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
```

The last part is the easiest. Open your /home folder in Nautilus, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to show hidden files.

Now just go to .local/share/applications, grab the icon with your mouse, and drag it to the Unity Launcher.

Credit to @451F 's answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/40327/12864), which I based this on.

Comment: should we use all the install.sh default paths?  they don't seem to be the ubuntu standard paths

Comment: @endolith not sure what you mean, is it the `./` part? If yes, [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Running_a_File_Within_a_Directory) might explain it better. If not I probably can't help any more as I uninstalled and quit using CrashPlan, it was rubbish.

Comment: I mean during setup it asks to put things in `/usr/local/crashplan`, `/usr/local/bin`, etc.

Comment: @endolith yes, use the defaults. If you have an encrypted `/home` the program is incompatible, it can't be used.

Answer (score 5):

from the terminal enter:

```
/usr/local/bin/CrashPlanDesktop
```

right-click on the launcher in the dock and click "Lock to Launcher"

Comment: Dead simple, and works! :-)

Comment: Yes, but you'll end up with duplicated icons in the launcher. http://askubuntu.com/questions/36434/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-icons-for-launched-java-programs-in-the-launcher