# multiple launcher icons when starting an app (dbeaver)

Tags: 18.04, launcher, icons

Maybe I just don't understand the idea of Ubuntus UX approach, but why does it show me two launcher icons when I start dbeaver?

On the left outer side you see the standard `dbeaver` icon, which is always in my launcher. When I click and run it, it shows me an additional icon (outer right side, also dbeaver icon).

[image]

I am using Unity on 18.04

Comment: I am not using Gnome but Unity

Comment: Did you manually install and log into Unity? 18.04 uses GNOME by default.

Comment: No in 18.04 you can choose at the log in screen between Wayland, X11, Unity

Comment: This should fix your issue: [How can I remove duplicate icons for “launched” java programs in the launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36434/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-icons-for-launched-java-programs-in-the-launcher)

Comment: This one provides detailed steps: [Duplicate icons for manually created GNOME launcher items](https://askubuntu.com/questions/403766/duplicate-icons-for-manually-created-gnome-launcher-items)

Comment: Where we can get dbeaver to reproduce (or not) your issue? Are you sure that right is beaver, not [Go Lang Gopher](https://golang.org/doc/gopher/frontpage.png)?

Comment: https://dbeaver.io/files/dbeaver-ce_latest_amd64.deb