# Not showing running application on the same added favourite app

Tags: launcher, 20.04, ubuntu-dock, gnome-dash

I installed Firefox Developer in ubuntu 20.04 and added to the dock. Then I added it as a favourite app. But whenever I click the app icon it launches but it showed as another app like this.

[image: like this]

How to solve this. I want to open it in the same launcher place.

Comment: did you install `unity` after a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04???

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/36434/739431

Comment: no, I did not install `unity`